# Xamarin.Forms calling On<iOS>(). methods without importing the name space?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've been struggeling a lot with this.
Whenever i try to do the following:

```
 MyPicker.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUpdateMode(Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
```

I need to import `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS` in my class to be able to call `SetUpdateMode`. Whenever i do import the namespace my whole code on this file is messed up because `Xamarin.Forms` specific classes will overlap and the compiler will throw a ton of errors.

I tried using an alternative namespace name for the import like this:

```
using iOSReallySpecific = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
```

without success.

I think this might be fixable with the use of Reflection, but i can't really find the exact solution for that problem anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias the static class `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Picker` (and the namespace `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific`):

```
using iOSSpecificPicker = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Picker;
using iOSSpecific = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
...
iOSSpecificPicker.SetUpdateMode(MyPicker, iOSSpecific.UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
```

Comment: Awesome! It finally works like that and i don't have to refactor any other code now.

Answer (score 0):

alias the namespace

```
using pc = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
```

then

```
MyPicker.On<pc.iOS>().SetUpdateMode(pc.iOSSpecific.UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
```

Comment: That's what i thought would work, but if i do it exactly like that the compiler throws a CS1061 error: `IPlatformElementConfiguration<iOS, Picker>" doesn't contain a  definition for "SetUpdateMode",`

Comment: `SetUpdateMode` is in `iOSSpecific`, not `iOS`

Comment: Yea, but how am I supposed to call it then? If i do `On<pc.iOSSpecific>.SetUpdateMode` it tells me iOSSpecific is a namespace but is used like a typ. I'm not getting the hang of it right now...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it, and it works. If using as follows:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
```

and then use it :

```
MyPicker.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
```

Comment: Yes, it works like that, but if i do this then I have to change everything inside that class that relates to the Xamarin.Forms namespace, which is really annoying and makes the code ugly. Is there no other solution?